# JainSIP, simple user registration

Tags: java, android, jain-sip

I've got a simple code for user registration. Of course, it doesn't work, because I'm new at Jain SIP stack, and I don't understand many things. I tried to imitate the Android SIP API, but unsuccessfully.

```
import javax.sip.SipFactory;
import javax.sip.address.Address;
import javax.sip.address.AddressFactory;
import javax.sip.address.SipURI;

public class SimpleUser {

    SipURI sipURI;
    Address address;
    AddressFactory addressFactory;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleUser().init();
    }

    public void init() {
        try {
            addressFactory = SipFactory.getInstance().createAddressFactory();
            //sipURI = (SipURI) address.getURI();
            sipURI = addressFactory.createSipURI("user", "domain");
            sipURI.setUserPassword("pass");
            //SipURI uri = (SipURI) addressFactory.createURI("sip:user@host");
            sipURI.setTransportParam("UDP");
            sipURI.setPort(5060);
            address = addressFactory.createAddress("user", sipURI);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Could someone direct me what I need to improve in order to properly connect to the SIP server.

PS. How can I check if the user has registered? I need something like a method isRegistered()

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending requests is a lot more involved I am afraid. See this [example](https://java.net/projects/jsip/sources/svn/content/branches/JAIN-SIP-WS-CLIENT/src/examples/wssclient/WSSClient.java?rev=2304), the `sendRegister()` method. This example uses websocket transport so you need to change to UDP. In fact you should probably go ahead and look into several examples to get the idea.